# I am looking to input a file in Perl and then export it changed

Tags: perl, file-io, edit, lines

I am looking to change a txt file in Perl, by input the file, then exporting it with a blank line in between the existing ones. How do i do this? I have this so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Hi! This Program Will Input\n";
print "The File and Export A New\n";
print "File With A Blank Line In-Between\n";
print "Every Other Line\n";
sleep(2);
print "\n";
print "\n";
print "Working\n";
print "\n";
sleep(1);
print "\n";
print "Working\n";
sleep(1);

open(my $in, "<", "input.txt") or die "Can't Open Input.txt: $!";
open(my $out, ">", "output.txt") or die "Can't Open Output.txt: $!";
my @lines = <$in>;
while (<$in>)  {
    print $out 
    print $lines[$#lines];
    print "    ";
}


print "Completed Successfully!!\n";
print "\n";
print "Outputed to Output.txt\n";


close $in or die "$in: $!"
```

What am i missing? I am only just learning Perl so i do not know much at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `while` loop. You can iterate over the filehandle with the `while`, or do a loop over the array where you saved the file content with `for`. Iterators can be processed once until they are exhausted, and you do it to extract all its content to the array, it's wrong to process it again in the `while` loop.

Besides that, to print to a filehandle you have to pass it as first argument to the `print()` function in the same call, and `"    "` is not a newline, `\n` is a newline.

```
my @lines = <$in>;
#while (<$in>)  {
for ( @lines ) { 
    print $out $_; 
    print $out "\n";
}
```

But you can forget all that code and learn the one-liners. This yields same result:

```
perl -ne 'print "$_\n"' input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked great! How would i reverse the process? I.E - Remove all the extra lines?

Comment: Surround the `print()` with a conditional sentence (`if`) checking if it's a blank line, either with a strict comparison `eq` or with a regular expression (`\s` or `\S` will be useful).